# Create a category list page

Tags: categories

I am trying to create a category list page that displays only the category titles with corresponding links.

It should not be PHP directly in the page. So how can I include a listing of categories on a page?

I am very new to WordPress and have searched many websites and found only how to list posts.

Please suggest a way I might be able to display categories.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To display a list of categories on your page by just putting something into the content area, you need a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode).

You can [create a shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) by using `add_shortcode`.  This defines the tag and the function to call when that shortcode is used.

Here's a basic example that creates a shortcode [my_cat_list]:

```
/**
 * This creates the [my_cat_list] shortcode and calls the
 * my_list_categories_shortcode() function.
 */
add_shortcode( 'my_cat_list', 'my_list_categories_shortcode' );

/**
 * this function outputs your category list where you
 * use the [my_cat_list] shortcode.
 */
function my_list_categories_shortcode() {
    $args = array( 'echo'=>false );
    return wp_list_categories( $args ); 
}
```

Adding this snippet to your theme's functions.php file will create the shortcode.

Placing the shortcode [my_cat_list] into a post or page will then display a list of categories with links to them.

The example uses `wp_list_categories()` in the shortcode function to display a list of categories.  The example just relies on the defaults for the function, but there are quite a few options for the way the list is output.  See the [documentation in the codex for wp_list_categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) for a **full** explanation of all of the defaults and options and what they do.

Comment: In which file i can add shortcode ?

Comment: That information is in the answer above, right after the code snippet.  The snippet can go in your theme functions file, then you can use the shortcode in any WP post or page.

Comment: this code isn't working anymore according to update in the default editor to gutenberg check this issue https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/3576 and the documentation of adding short cut https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

Comment: Your comment is both correct and incorrect, @shady sherif. It doesn't have anything to do with gutenberg. A shortcode should really never "echo" its result, but rather it should return it.  That's not a change - it's always been that way.  I'm not sure what I was thinking originally (this was originally posted in 2015), but regardless, thanks for mentioning it - I've corrected it accordingly.

Comment: @butlerblog I thought that it was working before because of the normal editor doesn't care if you print or return. But now the Gutenberg doesn't allow you to add a shortcode which doesn't return. Thanks for the fix

Comment: I know that the original question and answer were posted in 2015, but I have a follow up question on them, please. Is it better to display a list of categories (a) using a shortcode on a page (as the original poster asked for) or to (b) create a template for that page with the proper get_categories query coded in it? I mean, either way there will be some code added to functions.php or the template file... so why pick one way over the other? Is it a matter of best practices, practicality, or something else...?

Comment: @shadysherif - I think the Gutenberg editor probably is more strict, so it exposes the flaw of echoing the result. The previous editor let you get away with it even though it was incorrect.

Comment: @jsmod - it depends on the use case. If it needs to be portable (like a plugin), then maybe use a shortcode. If it's more customizing your specific instance and you're in a child theme, then the template file. There isn't a "right" answer - use the the option that makes the most sense for your specific use case.